# ITMS-90725 Useless error message, since it contradicts itself, Apple upload

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode13

how should i solve this issue?

**ITMS-90725: SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 15 SDK or later, included in Xcode 13 or later.**

It complaints about i need to build with iOS 15 SDK or later but also tells me i'm actually uses 15.5 SDK.

I also could swear that this error came only on 2 of my 3 pushed testflight builds and just today. (the last two)

I cross checked all my recent compiles and all are done with Xcode 13.4.1 and Build metadata shows 19F64.

I have apps in the store already so i'm a bit confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/ has a paragraph with "Please note, starting April 2023, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 14.1 and the iOS 16.1 SDK."

I guess the copy was not reviewed properly in the automated message :/

Comment: Yea i think so too, updating our CI Server to use XCode 14.x as we speak, just was a bit confused by the crappy error

Comment: Does someone know which date in April 2023 this will be enforced? Just got this notification today but we are 2 days away from April 1st so I want to know which date this will happen?

Comment: This starts on April 25, 2023. The email copy has been updated.